# Trying to create a CoordinatedShutdown helper function

Tags: scala, akka

I'm have a function that will do some cleanup code using the CoordinationShutdown flow.

```
 def shutdown(cs: CoordinatedShutdown, makePhase: CoordinatedShutdown.type => String, name: String)
    (f: () => Funit): Unit = {

      val phase = makePhase(CoordinatedShutdown)
      val msg = s"$phase $name"
      cs.addTask(phase, name) { () =>
        logger.info(msg)

        f()        
      }
  }
```

The current error is:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done]bloop
```

How can I call my future function f() and then return a akka.Done return type using Futures?

I tried:

f() andThen(akka.Done)

But then I get the error:

```
found   : akka.Done.type
 required: PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[Unit],?]
```

Can someone clarify what I am doing wrong and what I should be doing?

Comment: f().map(_ => Done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Future.map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html#map[S](f:T=>S)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) method to convert the value of the returned future to `Done`:

```
f().map(_ => Done)
```

This is similar to `andThen`, in that it executes a callback once the original `Future` completes, but with two important differences:

1. The `andThen` method does not change the value of the returned `Future`, so it can't be used to convert it to another type, as needed here.
2. The `map` callback only executes when the original `Future` completes successfully, and otherwise passes the original failure through, while the `andThen` callback is expected to handle either successful or failed results.

These are just two of several operations available on Scala `Future` objects. For a more complete overview, see the Scala documentation on [Futures and Promises](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html). There's a more in depth discussion in a series of posts on [Viktor Klang's blog](https://viktorklang.com/blog/).